# extract string from file at specific line in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract unit information from a text file. This function always returns 'm' regardless of the real unit in the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
def get_seba_unit(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        unit = ''
        lines = f.readlines()
        if lines[10].find('m'):
            unit = 'm'
        elif lines[10].find('cm'):
            unit = 'cm'
        elif lines[10].find('°C'):
            unit = '°C'
        print('found Unit: ' + unit + ' for sensor: ' + file)
        return(unit)
```

Comment: what does the line say? it's looking for an 'm' anywhere in the line, not just at the place you want it to look.

Comment: e.g. 01.01.2016 00:10:47 0,427 m

Comment: `find` returns position of occurence or `-1` if sequence not found. `-1` in `if` is interpreted as `True`.

Comment: and in your case first if statement will always get true if that line contains m character not in 0 index and all other if statement will get neglected

Answer (score 1):

This does not do what you think it does:

```
if lines[10].find('m'):
```

`find` returns the index of the thing you are looking for, or `-1` if it's not found.  So unless `m` is the first character on the line (index `0`), your condition will always be `True` (In Python a non-zero number is truthy)

You might want to try `if 'm' in line[10]` instead

Also, check for `cm` before `m`, otherwise you'll never find `cm`

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a way to extract out units from your data, i'd use some simple regex like the below one:

```
import io
import re
from collections import defaultdict

data = io.StringIO("""

1cm

2m

3°C

1cm 10cm

2m 20m

3°C           30°C

""")


def get_seba_unit(file):
    floating_point_regex = "([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)"
    content = file.read()
    res = defaultdict(set)

    for suffix in ['cm', 'm', '°C']:
        p = re.compile(floating_point_regex + suffix)
        matches = p.findall(content)
        for m in matches:
            res[suffix].add(m)

    return dict(res)

print(get_seba_unit(data))
```

And you'd get an output like this one:

```
{'cm': {'1', '10'}, '°C': {'3', '30'}, 'm': {'2', '20'}}
```

Of course, the above code is just assuming your units will be floating point units but the main idea would be attacking this problem using regular expressions.